# Trouble understanding excel formula is number search

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
0   0-1
0   0-1
0   0-1
0   0-1
0   0-1
0   0-1
0   0-1
0   0-1
0   0-1
0   0-1
0   0-1
1   0-1
1   0-1
```

What I am trying to do is to make this formula to search through 0 to 40 and divide into age bucket like if its 0 then show o-1 and if its 2 then show 2-5 how should I do that using excel formula. This is the formula I am using it but its not accurate

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("0",[@[Days IH]])), "0-1", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("1",[@[Days IH]])),"0-1",""))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CHOOSE(MATCH()):

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH([@[Days IH]],{0,2,11}),"0-1","2-10","11 and up")
```

Add bottom thresholds to the `{0,2,11}` and their corresponding return.